# Keycloak put request to update client role's associated roles

Tags: keycloak

I have a client role in Keycloak which I am trying to update its associated roles.
But i am getting a bad request when calling the admin API.

This is the API which I am calling.

PUT /admin/realms/{realm}/roles/{role-name}
Update a role by name.

This is my request payload

```
{
    "id": "0c80ac27-1788-4823-850c-8c2c0b53b6fa",
    "name": "Bus Operator",
    "description": "",
    "composite": true,
    "clientRole": true,
    "containerId": "b99076e7-1ebd-4085-a4ac-9a418cbfb8f3",
    "attributes": {},
    "composites": [
        {
            "id": "ad2202a3-836c-4431-a024-b29757b72389",
            "name": "TransportModeBus",
            "description": "",
            "composite": false,
            "clientRole": true,
            "containerId": "b99076e7-1ebd-4085-a4ac-9a418cbfb8f3",
            "attributes": {
                "functionCode": [
                    "33"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "7014b0d6-0d54-4ff4-93bb-28a86d0ff34e",
            "name": "ParameterMgmtSearchView",
            "description": "",
            "composite": false,
            "clientRole": true,
            "containerId": "b99076e7-1ebd-4085-a4ac-9a418cbfb8f3",
            "attributes": {
                "functionCode": [
                    "51"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "28da2d61-a7d9-4d2d-bf95-449d2863d7f4",
            "name": "ParameterMgmtSearchEdit",
            "description": "",
            "composite": false,
            "clientRole": true,
            "containerId": "b99076e7-1ebd-4085-a4ac-9a418cbfb8f3",
            "attributes": {
                "functionCode": [
                    "52"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "5c9ee932-6624-4ba6-aff4-785f871fac6f",
            "name": "ParameterMgmtSearchDelete",
            "description": "",
            "composite": false,
            "clientRole": true,
            "containerId": "b99076e7-1ebd-4085-a4ac-9a418cbfb8f3",
            "attributes": {
                "functionCode": [
                    "54"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Admin-UI uses the interface `/admin/realms/<REALMNAE>/roles-by-id/<roleid>/composites` with a payload of `[{"id":"120a5285-3ca8-4054-803f-b9b013ee7eba","name":"bar"}]` as POST or DELETE Request.
The PUT Interface, that you are using, is used only to modify name, description and attributes.